# Characters in cmd

Tags: batch, batch-file

I'm making a "command creator" so I saw that my batch didn't support the "@" character in the "`set`" command

Now, I tried setlocal, and it still wouldn't respond

is there any way to enable the "@" character in the "`set`" command?

Comment: Why do you want to use @ in the set command?

Comment: `set _test=@` works for me ...

Comment: Minecraft command generator